# How to check if there exists an element in a list less than equal to element in another list

Tags: java

Consider two Array list

```
a = [1,4,2,4] 

b = [3,5]
```

I wanted to return the count of numbers for each number in B less than equal to number in A.

So the answer would be `[2,4]` since 3 in B has 2 numbers in A that are <= 3  i.e. `[1,2]`

And 5 in B has 4 numbers in A that are  <= 5 . i.e `[1,4,2,4]`

Note: i tried using 2 loops but testcases time out.

this is the code

```
static ArrayList<Integer> counting(ArrayList<Integer>A, ArrayList<Integer>B)   
{
     
    ArrayList<Integer> finallist = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i : B)
    { 
        int count = 0;
        for(int j: A)
        {
            if(j<=i)
                count++;

           
        }
         finallist.add(count);
    }

    return finallist;
}
```

we were supposed to edit the function and return arraylist

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. Where are you stuck? What have you tried yet? I don't think it is useful for you, if somebody else writes the code for your assignments.

Comment: no it wasnt the assignment, it was a coding challenge. i tried using two loops but some test cases timed out.

Comment: Show us your code with the two loops.

Comment: okay give me a minute

Comment: @nehachawdipande if `A` contains [1,2,3,4,5] and `B` contains [2,3] what should be result?

Comment: Please don't add code to the comments, rather edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: ah thanks for the help. i was wondering how to do it

Comment: @ZahidKhan  then the answer should be [2, 3] since there are 2 elements in A that are less than equal  2 in B and there are [1,2,3] elements in A that are less than equal to 3

Comment: Try to sort list `A` and use binary search on it. It will improve performance.

Comment: yes thanks! precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from Your question was You weren't able to find the answer.
Hope this can help you.

Your code had a problem in counting function parameter, you should declare what is the data type that you are expecting.
`static ArrayList counting(List A, List B)` this isn't a way
instead you should have wrote `static ArrayList counting(ArrayList<Integer> A, ArrayList<Integer> B)`

and that will fix your problem.

here's my solution:

Counting function.

```
private static ArrayList counting(ArrayList<Integer>A, ArrayList<Integer>B ){
    ArrayList<Integer> finallist = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(int i : B) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j : A) {
            if(j <= i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        finallist.add(count);
    }
    
    return finallist;
}
```

Main from where am calling counting:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ans = counting(A,B);
        for(int i : ans) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
```

Output:

```
2 4
```

This could resolve the issue you are facing.

Comment: yes actually we just had to write the code inside  the methods so i was just giving an overview of the code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

When I see **an array** and I need **find** smth. in it, so this is a **magic key** to use **binary search**. This gives you `O(n log n)` time complexity.

```
public static int[] findLessNumbers(int[] a, int[] b) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> numCount = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int aa : a)
        numCount.put(aa, numCount.getOrDefault(aa, 0) + aa);

    int total = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : numCount.entrySet())
        numCount.put(entry.getKey(), total += entry.getValue());

    int[] res = new int[b.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
        res[i] = Optional.ofNullable(numCount.floorKey(b[i])).orElse(0);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: `findLessNumbers(new int[] {1,4,2,4},new int[] {0,5})` throws `NullPointerException`.